# How to find all callers of a node js function in sublime text 2 or 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

how to get all caller function list in sublime

For Example

```
file a.js 
 funtion hello(){}

file b.js 
 hello()
file c.js 
 hello()
```

here function hello called into file b and file c along with line number

How we can get this list in sublime

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not the proper way but use the global find option. Then you see every file.
2. But 'find usages' could be a package for sublime maybe... search in packages manager.
3. Other option is change the IDE to WebStorm or similar and use 'find usages'
4. Finally put a console log inside function and with the .caller property you should see origin , only when not in top level!